# Change http_basic_authenticate_with credentials on fly, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, authentication, actionmailer

I need that user can change ActionMailer settings on fly, without server restarting. I'm tryin do that on my mailer class

```
class CustomerMailer < ApplicationMailer
  self.smtp_settings = {
    address:             "smtp.gmail.com",
    port:                587,
    user_name:           settings[:delivery_email_login],
    password:            settings[:delivery_email_password],
    authentication:      "plain",
    enable_sarttls_auto: true
  }

  def customers_info_email(*some_args)
    # code
end
```

end

But changes take effect only after server restarting.

**Update**

Thanks to Anthony L change smtp settings dynamically already solved, but i have another question.

`http_basic_authenticate_with name: login, password: password`

How dynamically change authentication credentials for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the smtp_settings directly, use delivery_method_options on the mail method.  For instance:

```
delivery_options = {
        address:    "smtp.gmail.com",
        port:       587,
        domain:     "your_domain.com",
        user_name:  delivery_email_login,
        password:   delivery_email_password,
        authentication: :login,
        enable_starttls_auto: true
      }

mail(from: from_email, 
     to: to_email, 
     subject: subject,
     delivery_method_options: delivery_options)
```

See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html for more information.